# how to fix this verilog part-select error: Illegal operand for constant expression

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

So I'm having a input called tx_empty, and 255 bits data, my code is :

```
assign lastIndex  = (tx_eop)?  (tx_empty + 3'd4)*8 : lastIndex_xq;
wire [255:0] tmp1 = tx_data_xq[(tx_empty - 5'd16)*8-1 : 0];
wire [255:0] tmp2 = tx_data_xq[255:lastIndex];
wire [255:0] tmp3 = tx_data_xq[lastIndex +: 7'd96];
```

`tx_empty` is the input signal of this module, and "`lastIndex_xq`" is just the output of the D register of `lastIndex`. I want to change the index value when tx_eop is high.

`tmp3` works fine, I'm getting error like "Illegal operand for constant expression" for `tmp1` and `tmp2`, I know tmp2 is wrong because I cannot have a variable on the right hand side of a `:` in a part select. But how about tmp1? I have to use this part-select logic, is there any other way to do it?
Thanks in adv

Comment: From what I learned in other similar question,  the format should be like this: 

data[ const_or_var : const ] = { const { const_or_var } };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

verilog does not allow you to use variable widths in part select. Width must always be a constant. In your case it is not, because of *tx_emtpty* and *last_index*.

However, you can use bit shifts, masks and loops to handle it. Something like the following.

```
reg [255:0] mask1, mask2;
reg [255:0] tmp1, tmp2;
always @* begin
    // create mask of '1' of the required width
    mask1 = (256'b1 << (tx_empty - 5'd16)*8) - 1;
    tmp1 = tx_data_xq & mask1;
    mask2 = ~((256'b1 << lastIndex) - 1);
    tmp2 = (tx_data_xq & mask2) >> lastIndex;
end
```

Comment: Thank you, but the tmp3 works fine, which also uses the input variable. What is the reason for tmp3 to work?? I just added the logic of tmp3 in the description. Thx

Comment: yes, tmp3 uses `+:` syntax and operates a **constant** width of 96 bits.  You cannot use a var in the right hand side of this expression. Other two do not have constant widths and cannot  be expressed with `+:` or `-:` syntax.